# Deque to keep last few minutes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, deque

I'd like to keep the last 10 minutes of a time series in memory with some sort of deque system in Python.
Right now I'm using deque but I may receive 100 data points in few seconds and then nothing for few seconds.
Any idea ?

I read something about FastRBTree in a post but it dated back to 2014. Is there any better solution now?

I am mostly interested in computing the standard deviation over a fixed period of time, So the less data I receive within that fixed period of time, the less the standard deviation will be

Comment: The "last 10 minutes" of what?  Stock prices?  Surveillance video content?  Keyboard entries?  Temperature readings?  And you know python has a `dequeue` built in, right?

Comment: stock price for instance. A time series which does not receive update at constant interval. For now I am using deque indeed, but I'm never sure how much info I can receive within 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about container size, "simplest" thing might be to use the `deque` and just set a `maxlen` argument and then as it overflows, the oldest adds are just lost, but that does not guarantee 10 minutes worth obviously.  But it is an efficient data structure for this.

If you want to "trim by time in deque" then you probably need to create a custom class that can hold the data and a timestamp of some kind and then periodically poll the end of the deque for the time of the earliest item and keep popping until you are no later than current time + 10 mins.

If things are happening more dynamically, you might use some kind of database structure to do this (not my area of expertise, but seems plausible path to pursue) and possible re-ask a similar question (with some more details) as a database or `sqlite` question.

Comment: I am mostly interested in computing the standard deviation over a fixed period of time, So the less data I receive within that fixed period of time, the less the standard deviation will be

Comment: The standard deviation of the data "is what it is".  If you are estimating the standard deviation by sampling data, the less data you have, the worse your estimate is...